# Find element from jQuery matching objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a click event listener as below:

```
$(".clickable").click(function (e) {

  var results= $(e.currentTarget).closest('div.set').find('.clickable');
      // returns 
      //[<label for=​"thumbnail" class=​"clickable">​1 Malaysia​</label>​,
      //<div class=​"thumbnail clickable">​…​</div>​]

  var label = $(results).find('label'); // returns [] (empty list)

}
```

My problem is, how can I select the **label element** from the `results` list ? Thanks !

Comment: Also, in all likelihood `e.currentTarget` should be `this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `.filter()` instead of `.find()`,

```
var label = results.filter('label');
```

`.find()` will search for descendants, but here we are in need to filter out the required element from the collection, so use `.filter(selector)` here.

---

And also you could have simply used as satpal said like,

```
var results= $(e.currentTarget).closest('div.set').find('label.clickable');
```

Comment: @Unicorn, Just curious Why not `var results= $(e.currentTarget).closest('div.set').find('label.clickable');`?

Comment: @Satpal, cause I will be using the values in Div element later, simply personal preferences that I like to select one time for the general elements (`results`) then further filter in the children, instead of doing 2 almost-alike selection. Eg: `$(e.currentTarget).closest('div.set').find('label.clickable')` and `$(e.currentTarget).closest('div.set').find('div.clickable')`